# MySQL Query: LIMITing a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

Say I have two tables I want to join.
Categories:

```
id   name
----------
1    Cars
2    Games
3    Pencils
```

And items:

```
id   categoryid   itemname
---------------------------
1    1            Ford
2    1            BMW
3    1            VW
4    2            Tetris
5    2            Pong
6    3            Foobar Pencil Factory
```

I want a query that returns the category and the first (and only the first) itemname:

```
category.id category.name item.id item.itemname
-------------------------------------------------
1           Cars          1       Ford
2           Games         4       Tetris
3           Pencils       6       Foobar Pencil Factory
```

And is there a way I could get random results like:

```
category.id category.name item.id item.itemname
-------------------------------------------------
1           Cars          3       VW
2           Games         5       Pong
3           Pencils       6       Foobar Pencil Factory
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define "First"? It looks like the lowest ID value in item?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. By first I mean the lowest ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just done a quick test. This seems to work:

```
mysql> select * from categories c, items i
    -> where i.categoryid = c.id
    -> group by c.id;
+------+---------+------+------------+----------------+
| id   | name    | id   | categoryid | name           |
+------+---------+------+------------+----------------+
|    1 | Cars    |    1 |          1 | Ford           |
|    2 | Games   |    4 |          2 | Tetris         |
|    3 | Pencils |    6 |          3 | Pencil Factory |
+------+---------+------+------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I think this would fulfil your first question. Not sure about the second one - I think that needs an inner query with order by random() or something like that!

Comment: Having the results being random isn't that important to me, so this was really what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mysql lets you to have columns not included in grouping or aggregate, in which case they've got random values:

```
    select category.id, category.name, itemid, itemname
    inner join 
      (select item.categoryid, item.id as itemid, item.name as itemname
       from item group by categoryid)
    on category.id = categoryid
```

Or, for minimums,

```
select category.id, category.name, itemid, itemname
inner join 
  (select item.categoryid, min(item.id) as itemid, item.name as itemname
  from items
  group by item.categoryid)
on category.id = categoryid
```

Comment: I got an error when I tried this method: "Every derived table must have its own alias".
I guess I did something wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does let include non aggregate columns and there is no guarantee of determinism, but in my experience I nearly always get the first values.

So usually (but not guaranteed) this will give you the first

```
select * 
from categories c, items i
where i.categoryid = c.id
group by c.id;
```

If you want guaranteed you will need to do something like

```
select categories.id, categories.name, items.id, items.name
from categories inner join
  items on items.categoryid = categories.id and 
     items.id = (select min(items2.id) from items as items2 where items2.categoryid = category.id)
```

If you want random answers you will have to change the subquery a little bit

```
 select categories.id, categories.name, items.id, items.name
    from categories inner join
      items on items.categoryid = categories.id and 
         items.id = (select items2.id from items as items2 where items2.categoryid = category.id order by rand() limit 1)
```